# Why is constrainInput set to false not allowing me to type in custom characters?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the [jqueryUI datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput) widget, and I'm setting *constrainInput* to false so I can type in "n/a" or some other custom string in an input box with a class of *.some-date-field*.    Is there something off about the settings below?  Everytime I try to type a custom character it

```
$('.some-date-field').each(function() {
     $(this).datepicker({
       dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
       constrainInput: false
     });
   });
```

EDIT: here are the other javascript / jquery libraries being loaded in the page (part of a Rails 3.2 application)

*some_javascript.js and disagreement.js* are custom javascript files, although I don't think they are interfering with each other.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- JavaScript -->

    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/chosen.jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.anytime.compressed.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.bootstrap-editable.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.collapsible.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.cookie.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.formSavior.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.iframe-transport.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.metadata.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.tablesorter.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/some_javascript.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/disagreement.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_nested_form.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It appears to be working here with 1.11.0: http://jsfiddle.net/2o0gogjy/ Also, change `dateFormat` to `"mm/dd/yy"` or the selected year will appear twice in the input.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQueryUI 1.8.9

Comment: Just updated using your versions of jQuery and jQueryUI, and it still works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/2o0gogjy/1/ Can you post more information - has the DOM loaded when you attach datepicker? Is it possible these calls are overridden somewhere else in your code? Do you experience this in multiple browsers?

Comment: Thanks @Stiliyan, this happens in both Firefox and Chrome (haven't tested IE or any other browser).  My current guess is that it is possible the calls are overridden somewhere else, but I haven't been able to narrow it down.  Just looking for ideas.  I do enclose *$('.some-date-field').each* in a $(document).ready() so I assume the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Just realized there's the Anytime datepicker library being mixed in - I wonder if that's causing the issue?

Comment: Are the other plugins doing any proceeding on the form containing the datepicker inputs? Could you please create a jsfiddle reproducing the issue? See if this could help: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-date-picker-conflict

Comment: Unfortunately @Stillyan, I wasn't able to reproduce on jsfiddle because I couldn't include the Anytime datepicker library (no cdn for it).  But I did manage to solve the issue - it looked like there was a conflict between my custom js file and another, so I just didn't include the other js file on page load and that seemed to solve it.  Thanks for working this through with me!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you resolved it!